# Sensors to detect targets in low visibility environment

Tags: sensors, computer-vision

I want to know what type of sensor hardware I need to allow detection of moving targets (20mm - 200mm size range) in heavily murky water, where visibility range of typical camera can be limited to 0.5 meter and less.The operational range of the sensor can be not more than 10-20 meters. The goal is to detect organic bodies,estimate their size and count them using computer vision software like OpenCV. I am software guy and looking for an advice for the hardware part of this task.

Comment: i wonder if something like an electric eel can be duplicated with technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're probably aware, the sensor solution you're looking for is pretty much a research subject in itself. There have been [experiments](https://www.novuslight.com/seeing-through-murky-water-with-time-of-flight-cameras_N6063.html) using infrared time-of-flight cameras in murky water, and there are a few [devices](https://darkwatervision.com/) commercially available, but they're most certainly expensive and will require some engineering work to be adapted for a robotics application.

A relatively simpler option is to buy a set of [underwater infrared cameras](https://www.seaview.com/underwater-video-cameras-s/1814.htm) and implement range estimation in software, e.g. using OpenCV as you mentioned. Another alternative approach is to use sonar: there are [2D](https://bluerobotics.com/store/sensors-sonars-cameras/sonar/ping360-sonar-r1-rp/) and [3D](https://toposens.com/robotic-navigation/) sonars commercially available, or you could try to [build your own](https://hackaday.io/project/159297-ultrasonic-3d-scanner).